# Icon font is not displayed at Windows Phone devices

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, icons, windows-phone

No Font (both icon-font or normal font) is displayed on Windows Phone devices. I searched the web and stackoverflow and there are some "solutions".

- First to set the MIME type properly on an IIS server (I don't have an IIS server, just a shared webhosting server with Linux).
- Second solution is to host the font on an external server (which I did... I host them on my server, and referenced to them via the URL-scheme, and I also tried Google webfonts).

None of the solutions worked.
There is a known problem with external fonts and Windows Phone, but is there no possible solution? I just want to display some icons (via the Elegant-Icon-Font) on my WebPage which should work on all browsers.

**EDIT:** I'm talking of Windows Phone 7, 7.5 and 7.8!

**EDIT 2:** One dirty way is to replace the font-icons with .png (or .svg) files containing the actual icon. Then check if the user rides an IE under 10 and switch to the .png/.svg when he does. Not a pretty solution but it works.

Comment: So you are currently in the WP8 browser = IE10? - I've never experienced any issues like that. Can you provide a link for testing? FontAwesome references for instance work like a charm. At least for me.

Comment: Sorry no, I'm talking about Windows Phone 7 (or 7.5 and 7.8). When it works for Windows Phone 8 it's great news :) (at least)

Comment: Then, unfortunately I'm not able to help, but also curious if there is a solution to your problem :)